# $ω(G − S) = ω(G)$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

**Proposition:** Let $S$ be a stable set in a minimally imperfect graph $G$. Then $ω(G − S) = ω(G)$.

**Proof:** 
We have the following string of inequalities.
$ω(G − S) ≤ ω(G) ≤ χ(G) − 1 ≤ χ(G − S) = ω(G − S)$

Can someone help and say, why this inequalities in the proof hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for any graph $H$, we have $\omega(H) \le \chi(H)$, since coloring a clique of size $\omega(H)$ already requires $\omega(H)$ different colors. The graph $H$ is perfect if:

- equality holds: $\omega(H)= \chi(H)$, and
- moreover, equality holds for every induced subgraph of $H$.

If the graph $G$ is minimally imperfect, then all proper induced subgraphs $H$ of $G$ are perfect and satisfy $\omega(H) = \chi(H)$. If we had $\omega(G) = \chi(G)$, then $G$ would be perfect, so we must have $\omega(G) < \chi(G)$. Therefore $\omega(G) \le \chi(G)-1$, and we have proven one of the inequalities (the hardest).

The other inequalities are relatively easy to show.

1. $\omega(G-S) \le \omega(G)$ because removing vertices can't help there be a larger clique.
2. $\omega(G) \le \chi(G)-1$ as shown above.
3. $\chi(G)-1 \le \chi(G-S)$ because if we color $G-S$ with $k$ colors, we can color $G$ with $k+1$ colors by giving all of $S$ a color not used for $G-S$.
4. $\chi(G-S) = \omega(G-S)$ because $G-S$ is a proper induced subgraph of $G$, and therefore perfect.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the first sentence ''Recall that for any graph H..'' a graph H is mentioned as a graph and not as a subgraph?

Comment: Well, subgraphs are graphs. The first paragraph is a definition of "perfect graph" that can apply to any graph $H$, and later on we apply it to both $G$ (which is not perfect) and to all proper induced subgraphs of $G$ (which are).

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you.